# Remove a button in the kivy widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

In kivy, I try to remove a button in the widget but that doesn't work, I guess it's because my targeting is bad but I don't find on internet the good way to do it.

I would like to remove a button when I click on another button

```
class RPS(Widget):
    user_name_input = ObjectProperty()
    user_name = ''

    def save_user_name(self):
        user_name = self.user_name_input.text
        print(user_name)
        self.remove_widget(self.ids.remove) # I guess the problem is here the way I target
```

kivy file

```
user_name_input: user_name
TextInput:
    id: user_name
    size: 300, 50
    pos: 700,400
Button:
    text: "name"
    pos: 1070,400
    size: 300, 50
    on_release: root.save_user_name()
Button:
    id: remove
    text: "button to remove"
    pos: 1070,800
    size: 300, 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as follow. In the example, I used an ObjectProperty to hook up to the button to be removed because an id is a weakref to the widget. As ‘best practice’ use the ***ObjectProperty*** because this creates a direct reference, provides faster access and is more explicit. Please refer to example for details.

## main.py

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty


class RPS(BoxLayout):
    btn = ObjectProperty(None)
...
    self.remove_widget(self.btn) # I guess the problem is here the way I target
```

## kv file

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<RPS>:
    btn: remove
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty


class RPS(BoxLayout):
    btn = ObjectProperty(None)
    user_name_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    user_name = StringProperty('')

    def save_user_name(self):
        self.user_name = self.user_name_input.text
        print(self.user_name)
        self.remove_widget(self.btn)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RPS()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<RPS>:
    btn: remove
    user_name_input: user_name
    TextInput:
        id: user_name
        size: 300, 50
    Button:
        text: "name"
        size: 300, 50
        on_release: root.save_user_name()
    Button:
        id: remove
        text: "button to remove"
        size: 300, 50
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - Before Remove Button]
[image: Figure 2 - Button Removed]